# Oracle11g loop error when we insert data

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
CREATE PROCEDURE INSERT_CUSTOMER IS
    bill_address varchar2(100):='';
   v_oid varchar2(100):='';
CURSOR D1 IS SELECT OID FROM OMS.CUSTOMERINFO;
CURSOR C1 IS SELECT OID,BILLINGADDRESS FROM VENDOR;
  BEGIN
   FOR C2 IN C1  
   LOOP--   bill_address:=c2.billingaddress;
    FOR D2 IN D1
     LOOP
        IF c2.oid=D2.OID THEN
        INSERT INTO OMS.CUSTOMERINFO (BILLINGADDRESS) VALUES (c2.BILLINGADDRESS);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
  END;
```

I want to insert data in table"OMS.CUSTOMERINFO " using loop from the cursor.

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: [Error] PLS-00225 (8: 55): PLS-00225: subprogram or cursor 'C1' reference is out of scope

Comment: Are you sure you want to insert a record into `customerinfo` when there is already at least one is in there with the same `OID`? This code makes little sense, to be honest. Maybe you want to update billing address of a row in `customerinfo` that has the same `OID` as a row in the `vendor` table?

Comment: With this piece of code i  dont see any issue apart what @NicholasKrasnov mentioned. Is it a part of the whole program ?

Comment: when I try to compile that with schema inferred from question, I get a different error: "Error(11,12): PLS-00364: loop index variable 'C2' use is invalid". Are you sure that the error you mentioned corresponds to the code you posted?

Comment: this could probably be rewritten as a single update or merge statement without nested loops. what is the intention? add some DDL. it is not clear if CUSTOMERINFO would have a primary key OID column with a sequence, we can just guess